# golang local reverse proxy is rejected

Tags: go

```golang
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/a", func(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
        remote, _ := url.Parse("http://localhost:9000")
        proxy := httputil.NewSingleHostReverseProxy(remote)
        proxy.ServeHTTP(writer, request)
    })
 
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

In the local environment of reverse proxy prompt

```
http: proxy error: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9000: connect: connection refused.
```

Firewall has been turned off.  Can you tell me how to solve?

Comment: You should create the proxy only once and not for each request a new one. Apart from that,  you need to show more details. What is running on port 9000? Firewall shouldn't matter for local traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the URL http://localhost:9000 is working in your local.
If that's not working, it may be down.
If the http server is running on 9000 port, it will work.

If still not working, share the code details about http://localhost:9000 URL